# Unable to pass double forward slash in Python subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I've trying to use subprocess to run a system command, but when I pass a parameter with double forward slash the slashes are replaced with spaces.

Take this code:

```
i = subprocess.Popen(["netsed", "udp", "8080", "127.0.0.1", "8081", r"'s/X-Header: value//'"])
```

When the process is run, the last parameter is incorrect:

```
ps aux | grep netsed
root      783457  0.0  0.0   2692   804 pts/0    S+   17:00   0:00 netsed udp 8080 127.0.0.1 8081 's/X-Header: value  '
```

How do I pass the double forward slash?

Comment: This seems to work for me `subprocess.Popen(["echo", r"'s/X-Header: value//'"])` as does the "non-raw" version `subprocess.Popen(["echo", "'s/X-Header: value//'"])`. both result in `'s/X-Header: value//'`

Comment: I suspect it's `ps` that's doing this, not `subprocess`.

Comment: @JonSG Thanks, looks like the ps output was confusing the issue. thanks for the test which got me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The ps output was throwing me off.

What I actually needed to do was remove the quotes from the option, as it was automatically quoted by subprocess.

Thanks for the feedback.